# Modifying A* Algorithm to Make it Handle Different Cell Values

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, data-visualization

I wish to use the A* pathfinding algorithm on grids where each cell can have the values -1(wall), 1,2,3 or 4. A higher number indicates a higher cost to reach the cell, and -1 indicates that the cell is not walkable. I've been trying to modify the following implementation of the A* algorithm, which works for grids with cell values 0(walkable) or 1(wall). Here is a link to the algorithm which I have also pasted below: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Nicholas-Swift/003e1932ef2804bebef2710527008f44/raw/dfa6699f04a77c598daf8562d12cbb7fa2660263/astar.py

```
class Node():
    """A node class for A* Pathfinding"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position


def astar(maze, start, end):
    """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

    # Create start and end node
    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    # Initialize both open and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    # Add the start node
    open_list.append(start_node)

    # Loop until you find the end
    while len(open_list) > 0:

        # Get the current node
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)

        # Found the goal
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Generate children
        children = []
        for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares

            # Get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

            # Make sure within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # Make sure walkable terrain
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue

            # Create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # Loop through children
        for child in children:

            # Child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            # Create the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # Child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # Add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)
```

I know I at least need to change

`if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:`

to

`if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] < 0:`
to indicate that -1 is a wall. In addtion I changed

`child.g = current_node.g + 1`

to

`child.g = current_node.g  + maze[child.position[0]][child.position[1]]`

Since cells can have higher cost than one. However I don't know what else needs to be changed? If I only change these two things the algorithm will work for the following input:

```
maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

start = (0,0)
goal = (7,6)
```

But fail for this input where the code keeps running but never returns a path:

```
maze = [[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]]

start = [27, 18] 

goal = [40, 32]
```

Im also wondering how I can visualize the path the algorithm found? I know there are several options, I just want one that is simple to implement and displays the path in a clear manner.

Comment: This is an improvement but we need to see some input. What is the simplest input that yields the bad behaviour?

Comment: @AakashM Added example of input where the algorithm succeeds and one where it fails.